# Comparing Albert Camus and Karl Marx

Tags: ethics, reference-request, philosophy-of-law, justice

My brother is lawyer. He likes reading philosophy and writing about law.  He wants to find a source about a conflict ideas of revolution as you know Albert Camus and Karl Marx have.  He wants to write about an essay of their conflict.  He wants to compare The Rebel and The Communist Manifesto .Thanks for assistance.

Comment: Your brother, eh?

Comment: "Asking for a friend ..."

Comment: I'd look into the concept of alienation of labor, which they both describe in different terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds interesting. Could bring out some good contrasts, about the nature of freedom, and the systems we find ourselves in.

Camus is focused on the internal experience, the 'existential' encounter with meaning or lack of it. In The Rebel, this creates contact with transcendental values, not subject to corruption of ends-justifying-means.

Marx focused on classes of people, an essentially community-minded perspective. Zizek [claims atheist Marxism needs a Christian mindset](https://www.openculture.com/2013/11/slavoj-zizek-on-atheism.html). Marx's grandfather & uncle were rabbis, & Zizek has suggested communism be thought of as a kind of 'atheist reformation' of Judeo-Christian culture. Marx exactly failed to ensure contact of hus adherents with transcendental values, lost with the severing of spiritual practices.